# any method to show current user data in flutter form firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to show only currentuser data in drawer but unfortunately I get all registerd users email and name in drawer.[image: Image is attached for the reference]

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("users")
                    .where("uid")
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        var data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                        return UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                            accountName: Text(
                                data['first name'] + " " + data['last name']),
                            accountEmail: Text(data['email address']));
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                      child: Text('Loading Data......'),
                    );
                  }
                }),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!
```

Comment: Bundle of Thanks I am achieve this by using this 
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("users")
                    .where("email address", isEqualTo: currentUser.email)
                    .snapshots(),